# Luis Pre-built Entities geography not working with countrys

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I was trying the bre-built entities geography, but apparently does not work for international locations, such as Mexico, Guatemala, Honduras etc.

Do your have any suggestions?

I even try to add as a *Phrase List Features*

[image]

Comment: Never mind... I create my own Entity instead but it would be better if in the future can recognise international countries and locations.

Comment: P. Qrtiz I think you can send to the LUIS team to work on that. That will make them prioritize that!